# Blank desktop after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

Last night a window popped up on my version 13.10 desktop asking if I want to upgrade to 14.04.  I said yes, since you should keep software up to date and such.  The install went smoothly, but now it boots fine, gives me the user list, and boots to a blank desktop no matter what user I select.

There is no response to left or right clicking.  Pressing `<ctrl><alt><F1>` gives me a prompt:

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Media tty1
>
> Media Login:

There are a bunch of entries that talk about using `<ctrl><alt><F1>` to get a terminal prompt.  I can not get to a prompt.  `<ctrl><alt><T>` does nothing.  I really do not want to go to the trouble of re-copying all my media files, and re-installing and re-configuring Plex.

Is there any way to fix this?  If not, is there a way to revert to 13.10 or re-install 14.04 without destroying all my data and configuration?

Comment: It should say ctrl-alt-F1 gives the Media prompt, and ctrl-alt-T does nothing.

Comment: You can actually edit your posts to correct errors. I made the edits for you, changing the shortcut sections to code blocks.

Comment: The page linked above does not help.  When I try to run ccsm, I get a python error.  Also, many of the command given do not work because the directories are bad.  "/org/compiz/" for example.  There is no /org directory.

The problem may or may not be something to do with nvidia drivers.  This is totally frustrating, and I wish I never upgraded.  I am about ready to restore the disk the image I made before I removed windows.

I would be happy to reinstall, if I could do so without wiping the drive.

Comment: "I said yes, since you should keep software up to date and such."  I don't dare even an update; forget about a stable system after an upgrade.

Comment: @user272468. Did you resolve this? If so, please share the solution or accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

In the user interface press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Then a command line shows.Type your login account and password.

Type the following commands

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo reboot
```

In the login screen change the Desktop Environment(DE) to gnome.Then again back to Ubuntu default.