# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation completed but after click on restart button it doens't restart

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I have problem with Ubuntu 14.04 installation. I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7559 notebook and UEFI.

Specs:

- 15.6-inch (3840 x 2160) 282ppi IPS touchscreen, glossy finish
  Windows 10 Home
- 2.6GHz Intel Core i7-6700HQ (3.5 GHz Turbo) 4 cores
- 8 threads
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M with 4GB GDDR5 + Intel HD Graphics 530
- 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L RAM

I wanted to dual boot Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu, so I step by step did the installation of the latest version. It was successful (but only when I changed parameters and added `nomodeset`), but after some time I noted that some programs froze or there were error messages (with some internal errors).

I found advice on the internet that said that 14.04 is a better version for my notebook, so I uninstalled the newest version (through Windows (remove partitions) and with program dual boot Repair Windows 10 repair boot and tried again to install an older version of Ubuntu.

It went normally without an error and again as previously separate HDD on two blocks and use the second on 3 partitions as in the guide. When I did all this it finally showed a message that everything was finished and restart your computer.

When I clicked the button the system didn't restart. It got stuck at a screen with mouse animation doing something, so it didn't finish the whole installation which should end by restarting (after clicking). It was just stuck at that screen and nothing else, so I had to force shutdown.

[image: Here picture of it]

After many things from both pots and another I could successfully login to the desktop without errors or parameters, but got international errors from xorg after login `/usr/bin/xorg` -> which after some other research maybe is fixed by updates and reinstalling apport.

I have another big problem and it's that I still can't reboot or shutdown without sometimes CPU stuck (NMi watchdog). This stuck I previously when I had 16.04 fixed by swap on Nvidia but the 2nd post didn't work, moreover I can't without black screen swap to Nvidia driver. I tried 4x different driver versions.

I know that have many errors and better I would just format block with Ubuntu and have only Windows with 1TB HDD, and after some time buy a second HDD or SSD, but I still didn't want to give up, however after another try I admitted my inexperience with Linux, so I decided to uninstall it with OS-Uninstaller using a live USB. Maybe after some time I'll try again to install Ubuntu. Maybe when I have another HDD/SSD.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say I have had this problem before, but I did some research and found a solution similar to what you are experiencing. If for some reason you were able to resolve it before reading this post, please post how you fixed it to help someone else. Please follow this link below;

[Blank desktop after upgrade to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452845/blank-desktop-after-upgrade-to-14-04)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i dont think that this post will help me, its true its similary problem but he have problem after succesfull instal and "restart" and he got this problem when he login in. Difference is that my installation after all things doesnt finish with restart but "stuck"(restart is last part of installation to save all changes i think)

Comment: My guess is you may be having issues with your partition. My only suggestion to you will be to uninstall the linux program and install a virtualBox. You can install your Ubuntu 14.04 inside the virtualBox so you don't end up breaking your system. Trust me it is a safer way until you can do more research to resolve the other problem. Please follow this video tutorial link for details. Sorry I couldn't be much help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1rYoH_XwFc.